# Why sliding drawer not accepting layout width as fill_parent or match_parent

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

If i use layout width as 100dip or 50 dip then my sliding drawer is working fine, it shows `Sliding drawer cannot have unspecified dimension` when using layout width as fill_parent or match parent. i dont know what mistake i have done,
check it out my layout

```
 <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/gocashHistorylist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

within my sliding drawer i have used listview, so for me it must to use layout width as fill parent, 
please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [refer this] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
Hope this help you

Comment: Did you ever used this? because as like that document i have used sliding drawer inside the framelayout but no luck. same error occurred.